# Locally test different domain url configuration in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, session, cross-domain

As the title says how do i test different domain **not** subdomain url routing?

I'm using a middleware as follows:

```
class MultipleDomainMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):


        def process_request(self, request):

            url_config = getattr(settings, 'MULTIURL_CONFIG', None)
            if url_config is not None:
                host = request.get_host()
                if host in url_config:
                    request.urlconf = url_config[host]
```

Where the `url_config[host]` value points to `app.urls` in the settings `MULTIURL_CONFIG` dictionary. Each app is on a different domain.

Now, when locally testing I'm on localhost:8000/ so how can I test this so I can test my routing schema as well as shared data across the domains locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i didn't misunderstood your question and you're using linux, you could add to /etc/hosts file next to localhost all the domains that you want to test

for example:

```
# /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1     localhost mydomain pudipudi
```

then you can go to your browser to `pudipudi:8000`

Comment: That'll work. Wasn't sure if i could do this with domains instead of subdomains as well. Thanks, I'll see if this works for also testing shared data across the domains. Will accept when I can :)

Comment: Happy to know that was helpful!