# How to use StaticLiveServerTestCase with different domains?

Tags: django-testing

I am using selenium for functional tests with geckodriver and firefox.

I see the host is `http://localhost:62305` and this is generated in that class with:

```
@classproperty
def live_server_url(cls):
    return 'http://%s:%s' % (cls.host, cls.server_thread.port)
```

In the functionality I am creating, I give the user a way to create a tenant with its own subdomain but for the purpose of the unit test it can be a domain.

So for example I create a tenant with domain `example.com`, how can I get 
`StaticLiveServerTestCase` to point that domain name to the currently running app on that same port, within the same functional test method.

I looked at this [post suggesting editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46748659/locally-test-different-domain-url-configuration-in-django) `/etc/hosts`. The problem with that is it won't just work on CI and other people's computers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this.

```
class SeleniumTests(StaticLiveServerTestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.host = 'host.com'
        cls.port = 3000
        super(SeleniumTests, cls).setUpClass()
       ....
```

in your test class and once you do this for instance

`self.selenium.get('%s%s' % (self.live_server_url), 'some_url')`

your browser gonna be launch with the right URL like this
`http://host.com:3000/some_url/`,
notice how the super call is made after setup the port and host.